# Robot framework setting suite variables

Tags: robotframework

In Robot framework script I am trying to choose communication protocol (telnet or ssh) to be used by individual suites. I've tried the implementation described below, but it doesn't work.

Could some one help, or share a better proposal for implementation?.

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup       Custom Suite Setup
Library           ${suiteCommProtocol}

*** Keywords ***
Custom Suite Setup
    ${suiteCommProtocol} =    Set Variable    Telnet
    Set Global Variable    ${suiteCommProtocol}    Telnet
```

Comment: "I've tried the implementation described below" - It's clearly invisible because I cant see it..?

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include

Comment: I now modified the question to include code also.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @Bryan Oakley's answer, a better implementation might be to create your Resource file with a Variables section and set a variable to Telnet, then use the variable in the Custom Suite Setup keyword.

```
*** Variables ***
${suiteComm}    Telnet

*** Keywords ***
Custom Suite Setup
    ${suiteCommProtocol} =  Set Variable    ${suiteComm}
    Set Global Variable     ${suiteCommProtocol}    ${suiteComm}
    Import Library  ${suiteCommProtocol}
```

This way, you can switch between Telnet and ssh by simply changing the one variable at the top of the Resource file. I don't claim to understand exactly what his code is doing, but I do know how to make sure that you can change everything with one variable.

Answer (score 0):

The imports happen before any keywords are run, so it's impossible to use a variable in a settings table based on a variable created by a keyword.

If you want to load a library at run time, use the built-in keyword [import library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Library)

```
*** Keywords ***
Custom Suite Setup
    ${suiteCommProtocol} =    Set Variable    Telnet
    Set Global Variable    ${suiteCommProtocol}    Telnet
    import library    ${suiteCommProtocol}
```